# Copying a struct member into a new struct

Tags: c, struct, global

I have a structure outlined below:

```
typedef struct {
    /* Device */
    UART_DEV uartDev;
    /* gpio */
    uint32_t gpiopio;
} DEVICE;
```

In main.c I declare a new uart device and pass it to a function called configure();

```
/* main.c */

static UART_DEV newUartDev;
configure(newUartDev);
```

`configure()` is located in test.c and inside the configure function I want to create a copy of the uart device and store it in global memory.

```
/* Test.c */

UART_DEV globalUartDev;
DEVICE globalDevice;

static int configure(UART_DEV newUartDev) {
    /* Create a global copy of spi device */
    globalUartDev = newUartDev;
    DEVICE.uartDev = globalUartDev;

}
```

Then I call another function in main.c `setTest`. setTest is located in test.c. I do not pass it the uart device declared in main.c instead I want to just use the global struct I created previously. `setTest` calls `open` in dev.c

```
/* test.c */

setTest() {
    open(&globalDevice);
}
```

and finally I will use the uart device in open.

```
/* dev.c */
int  open(DEVICE *dev) {
read(dev->uartDev)
}
```

Is this the correct way to create a copy and pass it around files?

Comment: Globals are evil.

Comment: @MichaelWalz is it better than to keep passing the file from main.c all the way through?

Comment: Don't write a novel describing your code, but post the **actual** code as a [mcve].

Comment: Globals are evil (as stated above)... prefer to make use of a 'context' that is passed around. The 'context' should describe everything that is required to use (in this case) the UART. This way you can use multiple UARTs with only one set of access functions.

Comment: @homeGrown, if there are data that need to be shared between functions, even across many functions, then ***yes***, it is better to pass (a pointer to) them from function to function than to declare global variables to hold them.

Comment: As for the code you've posted, follow @Olaf's helpful link to discover what a MCVE comprises.  You have not yet provided one.  Particularly notable in its absence is the definition of the `UART_DEV` type, which could make a great deal of difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
DEVICE.uartDev = globalUartDev;
```

`DEVICE` is not an object, it is a structure.`globalDevice` is an object.So it should be

```
globalDevice.uartDev = globalUartDev;
```

Comment: `DEVICE` is a `typedef` for a `struct`, and `globalDevice` is a `DEVICE` `struct`.